# Center the content inside shape HTML

Tags: html, css

This what I get
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGQiR.png

I want it like this
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu7g5.png

Here is my code, this is the CSS file.

```
.shape{
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  color:#4F5E73;
  margin:20px auto;
  background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
  text-align:center;
}
```

This is how I show the shape and text.

```
<div class="shape">
  <span style="font-size:72px;"> 7 </span> <br />
  <span style="font-size:18px;"> minutes to Applecross High School </span> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to align it vertical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, add padding to `.shape` and to align everything in center and within our assigned `height` and `width`, so for that we have included `box-sizing:border-box;` this tells browser to include padding within element's `height` and `width` (i.e. overe-here is .shape).

```css
.shape {
  width:210px;
  height:250px;
  color:#4F5E73;
  background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <span style="font-size:72px;"> 7 </span>
  <span style="font-size:18px;"> minutes</span><br>
  <span>to Applecross High</span> 
  <span>School </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: thank ! that really help, its work.

Comment: Welcome @JalonJuanis :-)

Comment: @JalonJuanis Do accept the answer if above code helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` for modern browsers.
css:

```
  .shape{
      display:flex;
      align-items: center;
      width:200px;
      height:250px;
      color:#4F5E73;
      margin:20px auto;
      background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
      text-align:center;
  }
```

you should use some fallbacks for -webkit- and so on

Comment: thank you, its work but the content has mixed, how can i separate it two line? I want the number as a heading.

Comment: just add the following to your css: `.shape span { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="vert-align">
    <span style="font-size:72px;"> 7 </span> <br />
    <span style="font-size:18px;"> minutes to Applecross High School </span> <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #4F5E73;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  text-align: center;
}
.shape .vert-align {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution which is supported across browsers do sth like this:

HTML

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="shape__inner">
    <span style="font-size:72px;">7</span>
    <span style="font-size:18px;">minutes to Applecross High School</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shape {
    width:200px;
    height:250px;
    color:#4F5E73;
    margin:20px auto;
    background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
    text-align:center;
}

.shape__inner {
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Check a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nxs6w20t/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[This jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4ks1czn/) can be a possible solution for your problem.

```css
 .shape {
   width: 200px;
   height: 250px;
   color: #4F5E73;
   margin: 20px auto;
   background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
   text-align: center;
 }
 
 span {
   position: relative;
   top: 20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <span style="font-size:72px;"> 7 </span>
  <br />
  <span style="font-size:18px;"> minutes to Applecross High School </span>
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work, this is the answer.

```css
.shape {
  width:210px;
  height:250px;
  color:#4F5E73;
  background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
  text-align:center;
  padding:50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <span style="font-size:72px;"> 7 </span>
  <span style="font-size:18px;"> minutes</span><br>
  <span>to Applecross High</span> 
  <span>School </span> 
</div>
```